# Generic List<Type> to enum

Tags: c#, list, enums

i have the following Class

```
public partial class ActionType
{
    public System.Guid ActionTypeId { get; set; }
    public string ActionTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to use all ActionTypes stored in the database like this:

```
MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
entity.ActionTypeId = ActionTypes.???
```

here i want to be able to select the ActionTypeId by ActionTypeName.

Now I'm doing it this way:

```
public class ActionTypes
{
    public static readonly Guid CustomerAdded = new Guid("36520b53-e1d0-4c96-bec8-0df85536a96b");
    public static readonly Guid CustomerEdited = new Guid("732592d3-7423-4250-aa74-e10fe1e7c030");
}
```

I want to be able to create ActionTypes programmaticaly from the database, not to write the values by myself.

So i want to do something like:

```
public class ActionTypes
{
   List<ActionType> list = context.GetAllActionTypes();
   foreach(ActionType type in list)
   {
      public static readony Guid type.ActionTypeName = type.ActionTypeId;
   }
}
```

How can I implement what I intend?

best regards

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Does a `Dictionary<string, Guid>` help?

Comment: It's terribly unclear what you're asking here. The code you have works, what is it you want differently?

Comment: Sorry guys, i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Dictionary (Lookup-table, map) is what you need?

```
public class ActionTypes
{
   private List<ActionType> list = context.GetAllActionTypes();
   private Dictionary<string, Guid> ActionTypesMap { get; private set; }

   public ActionTypes() {
     this.ActionTypesMap = list.ToDictionary(
       k => k.ActionTypeName,
       v => v.ActionTypeId);
   }
}
```

Access as: `Guid addedGuid = new ActionTypes().ActionTypesMap ["CustomerAdded "]`

Comment: i can achieve the same by doing: Guid addedGuid = list.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ActionTypeName == "CustomerAdded").ActionTypeId;

Comment: Then how do you want to refer to your action types? You need to know the name somehow. I know you could do it with FirstOrDefault (dictionary is faster but uses more memory).

Answer (score 0):

You could use a T4 template to generate the file at compile-time.  This has the added benefit of keeping Intellisense and verification of member names.

Something like this:

ActionTypes.tt:

```
<#@ template   language    = "C#"                           #>
<#@ assembly   name        = "Microsoft.CSharp"             #>
<#@ assembly   name        = "System.Core"                  #>
<#@ assembly   name        = "System.Data"                  #>
<#@ import     namespace   = "System.Collections.Generic"   #>
<#@ import     namespace   = "System.Dynamic"               #>
<#@ import     namespace   = "System.Linq"                  #>
<#@ import     namespace   = "System.Data.SqlClient"        #>

public class ActionTypes 
{
<#
var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();

var sqc = new SqlCommand("SELECT ActionTypeID, ActionTypeName FROM ActionTypes", con);
var reader = sqc.ExecuteReader();

using (var reader = sqc.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
#>
    public static Guid <#=reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ActionTypeName"))#> = new Guid("<#=reader.GetGuid(reader.GetOrdinal("ActionTypeID"))#>");
<#
    }
}
con.Close();
#>
}
```